# Given a subset of attributes on a class instance, increment one randomly

Tags: python

I have a Python class as such:

```
class Zoo:
  pandas = 0
  tunas = 0
  cows = 0

  #...other attributes and methods below
```

Because of divine forces outside of my control, I **cannot modify the class in any way whatsoever** (yes, I realize a dictionary of animals would be better here). I would like to write code which will operate on an instance of the class, and increment a random attribute amongst the 3 shown above by 1.

In essence, I'd like to write something like this:

```
import random
z = Zoo()
attributes = [z.pandas, z.tunas, z.cows]
random.choice(attributes) += 1
```

Of course, this doesn't work. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Apparently "tunas" really *is* an acceptable pluralization of tuna.  The more you know.

Comment: @roippi: Yes, and both "tuni" and "tunae" are incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
attributes = ['pandas', 'tunas', 'cows']
choice = random.choice(attributes)
setattr(z, choice, getattr(z, choice) + 1)
```

Comment: Haha, yes, I always forget about setattr. Thanks!